# Zend_Form doesn't load on deployment

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Can't figure this one out. It worked in my local environment. Everything is at the right place but the server still can't find it:

**Warning: include_once(Zend/Form/Element/TextArea.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /is/htdocs/xxxx/www/mensenenjij/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/Form/Element/TextArea.php' for inclusion (include_path='/is/htdocs/xxxx/www/mensenenjij/application/../library:/is/htdocs/xxxx/www/mensenenjij/library:.:/usr/share/pear/php5') in /is/htdocs/xxxx/www/mensenenjij/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form_Element_TextArea' not found in /is/htdocs/xxxx/www/mensenenjij/library/Mensenenjij/Form/Contact.php on line 52**

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming by the class it's trying to load, you're using Windows on your local env, and a Linux distro on your deployment server?

If you are, Linux is case sensitive. Try using `Zend_Form_Element_Textarea` instead.

Comment: wow wtf, thanks for this! mac is my local env, and linux is my deployment.  why exactly is this happening?

Comment: Mac OS uses Apple's HFS+ file system, which like Windows' NTFS and FAT, is case insensitive. By using the class name `Zend_Form_Element_TextArea`, the autoloader loads the file `lib/Zend/Form/Element/TextArea.php` which doesn't exist in case sensitive file systems.